# How to make a 100% stacked chart using the following 2 charts in SAS?

Tags: sas, sas-visual-analytics

This is the code:

```
proc sgplot data=work.simple pctlevel=group;
  title 'Group Y Portfolio(2007/2008/2009/2010)';
  vbar Companies / group=Year stat=pct seglabel groupdisplay=stack ; 
run; 
proc sgplot data=work.simple pctlevel=group;
  title 'Group Y Portfolio(2007/2008/2009/2010)';
  vbar Companies /  group=Year stat=pct seglabel groupdisplay=cluster ; 
run;
```

Please take a look at these 2 charts. How can I combine?[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpWjT.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrUow.png)

Comment: What do you mean combine? What do you want as output?

Answer (score 0):

I think this blog gives you the answer:

[Construct a stacked bar chart in SAS where each bar equals 100%](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2014/04/08/construct-a-stacked-bar-chart-in-sas-where-each-bar-equals-100.html)

Code from the blog to use as template:

```
proc freq data=cars order=freq noprint;  /* ORDER= sorts by counts within X */
by Origin;                               /* X var */
tables Type / out=FreqOutSorted;         /* Y var */
run;
 
title "100% Stacked Bar Chart Ordered by Percentages";
proc sgplot data=FreqOutSorted;
vbar Origin / response=Percent group=Type 
              grouporder=data groupdisplay=stack; /* order by counts of 1st bar */
xaxis discreteorder=data;
yaxis grid values=(0 to 100 by 10) label="Percentage of Total with Group";
run;
```